# How to get ruby version with patch number

Tags: ruby

I want to get ruby version with patch number.
But `RUBY_VERSION` returns only first three numbers.

So I wrote like this:

```
`ruby -v`.gsub(/ruby (\d\.\d\.\dp\d+) .*\n/, $1)
```

But it's a little tricky. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Note that probably only MRI rubies have a patch level (i.e. not JRuby and not Rubinius).

Comment: Hi Holger :) jruby 1.7.4 returns `392` when asking for the `RUBY_PATCHLEVEL`. Don't know about rubinius, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant [`RUBY_PATCHLEVEL`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#RUBY_PATCHLEVEL) gives you the current patch level.

```
RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.0.0"
RUBY_PATCHLEVEL
=> 247
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the [**source**](http://rubyforge.org/snippet/detail.php?type=snippet&id=475) of those constants or You could get the list this way also:

```
Object.constants.grep(/^RUBY/)
# => [:RUBY_VERSION,
#     :RUBY_RELEASE_DATE,
#     :RUBY_PLATFORM,
#     :RUBY_PATCHLEVEL,
#     :RUBY_REVISION,
#     :RUBY_DESCRIPTION,
#     :RUBY_COPYRIGHT,
#     :RUBY_ENGINE]

Object.constants.grep(/^RUBY/).each_with_object({}) {|e,h| h[e]=Object.const_get e}
# => {:RUBY_VERSION=>"2.0.0",
#     :RUBY_RELEASE_DATE=>"2013-02-24",
#     :RUBY_PLATFORM=>"i686-linux",
#     :RUBY_PATCHLEVEL=>0,
#     :RUBY_REVISION=>39474,
#     :RUBY_DESCRIPTION=>
#      "ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]",
#     :RUBY_COPYRIGHT=>"ruby - Copyright (C) 1993-2013 Yukihiro Matsumoto",
#     :RUBY_ENGINE=>"ruby"}
```

Answer (score 1):

`RUBY_PATCHLEVEL` may be of interest to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work `"#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"`